# TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment - python function

Tags: python

I am getting this error **TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment**
I don't get this in javascript I don't understand what I need to change in my code

```
def count_word_frequencies(text):
    word_frequency_dict = {
        "coffee": 0
    }

    list = text.split()  
    dict["coffee"] = list.count('coffee')
    return word_frequency_dict
```

Comment: please provide the traceback in your question so we can see where the error is raised

Comment: Avoid making variables with built-in key words like `list` & `dict`

Comment: You apparently haven't actually created a dict, you're trying to store data in the `dict` type itself.  (And `list` is likewise an inappropriate name for a list, you're overwriting a rather important built-in name.)

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
def count_word_frequencies(text):
    word_frequency_dict = {
        "coffee": 0
    }

    list = text.split()  
    dict["coffee"] = list.count('coffee')
    return word_frequency_dict
```

`dict` is a protected function and shouldn't be used as a user-defined variable. Your error is raised because you didn't declare `dict` to be a variable so it assumes you are using the python defined function. To avoid the error you'll need to declare a `dict` object first.

Try this:

```
def count_word_frequencies(text):
    word_frequency_dict = {
        "coffee": 0
    }

    a_dict = dict()

    some_list = text.split()  # note that I also changed `list` to `some_list`
    a_dict["coffee"] = some_list.count('coffee')
    return word_frequency_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

`dict` is a type. You can use `dict()` function to create an empty dictionary without passing any arguments or pass keyword arguments as a parameter with the required values that will be keys and values of the dictionary, like  `dict(coffee=0)`.

Avoid using built-in name as variable, as suggested by others.

```
def count_word_frequencies(text):
    word_frequency_dict = dict(coffee=0) # word_frequency_dict = {'coffee': 0 }
    lst = text.split()
    word_frequency_dict['coffee'] = lst.count('coffee')
    return word_frequency_dict

print(count_word_frequencies('is that my coffee or your coffee ?')

# {'coffee': 2}
```